# Automatically switch XCode to Project Navigator after debugging

Tags: xcode

Upon hitting a break point in XCode it switches the left most panel to the Debug Navigator. If I then stop debugging the panel maintains the Debug view and contains the text...

> No Debug Session

Then I like to manually switch the panel back to the Project Navigator in order to carry on developing.

Is there a way of configuring XCode such that it automatically switches to the panel layout it had when I started debugging the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode, go to Xcode -> Behaviors -> Edit Behaviors. Select Running | Pauses in the left section of the dialog. In the main section, choose Show Project Navigator.

The Behaviors feature in Xcode is quite powerful for customizing the workflow. I actually like to have separate tabs for editing code, building and running. You can configure the behaviors to switch to the appropriate tab (which is configured to your liking) whenever you build or run the app. Really useful. I think I've learned about it from one of the older WWDC videos about the efficient use of Xcode.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a way to return the editor's open file to the previous one though. It stays on the code that was debugged.

Comment: If you want to return to the file you've been editing, I think your best bet is separate tabs for editing and debugging. See my edited answer.

Comment: BTW, I like to switch tabs with the key combinations Command+Shift+] and Command+Shift+[. Faster that doing it with the mouse.